# Working off mounted drive - Linux

Tags: linux, mount

Say I have the following mount points:

```
/dev/sda1 on /
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/sdb1
```

sda is my primary hard disk drive. sdb is a second disk drive.

This might be a silly question, but does it make any difference to performance (copy, write ect..) if I work on sdb1 from a sim-linked path on sda?

So say I have the following sim link on sda:

```
/home/sim-to-sdb -> /mnt/sdb1
```

Does it make any difference to disk read/write performance if I work on

```
/home/sim-to-sdb
```

or

```
/mnt/sdb1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be any difference...the link is just a pointer to where your drive is mounted. Is there a reason you're suspecting a difference? If you're seeing performance degradation you might want to check the smarttools to and hdparm to find what its settings are, and/or check the cabling on the drives  (loose cables? mis-set parameters? Sharing bus with something like a DVD drive sucking I/O?)